# Explode e comparar valor em um Select?

Tags: php, mysql, select

No meu MySql tenho a seguinte coluna `data_id` a mesma armazena valores nesse formato `120-01-01`, como seria um `SELECT` que fizesse um `EXPLODE` nesse campo e verifica se o primeiro valor do `array` que no caso seria `120`, bate com o valor digitado?

Usando apenas PHP seria fácil dar um `explode('-', $data_id)` e então comparar se  a primeira chave bate com o valor desejado, mas isso me obrigaria a pesquisar todos os valores da tabela antes, o que é fora de cogitação por motivos óbvios, então eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o mesmo dentro do `SELECT`.

Obs: tal coluna não é um campo tipo `date`, e sim um `varchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que isso seja o que você quer:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX($data_id, '-', 1)
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Comment: Entendo é que no caso o select é simples mesmo, mas de qualquer forma, explicando, esse select que postei retornará o primeiro item antes do -, o que é similar ao explode do php, para saber mais a respeito do funcionamento de SUBSTRING_INDEX, ao digitar no google vários links confiáveis aparecerão, sendo um deles:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Se for sempre 3 caracteres, você pode fazer o seguinte select

```
SELECT data_id, LEFT( data_id , 3 ) as codigo
  FROM sua_tabela
 WHERE LEFT( data_id, 3 ) = $variavel_que_esta_procurando
```

Agora se forem tamanhos diferentes, tente usar o que a função que foi respondida anteriormente

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_id, '-', 1)
```

Qualquer dúvida é só entrar em contato.

Abraços, Tonico